# Ansible - template from dictionary item

Tags: ansible, dictionary, template

Ansible - template from dictionary item 
1'st:
Trying to write task which creates files from template

```
NODES:
  node1:
    server: host1
    script: manage1
  node2:
    server: host2
    script: manage2
  node3:
    server: host3

- name: Create files from templates
  template:
    src: "templ.j2"
    dest: "/etc/init.d/{{item.key}}"
  loop: "{{NODES|dict2items}}"
  when: "{{ 'script' in item.value }}"
```

Above creates files:

```
/etc/init.d/node1
/etc/init.d/node2
```

I can't find a way to get:

```
/etc/init.d/manage1
/etc/init.d/manage2
```

2'nd question:
during looking for above changed dictionary into list of hashes, ( I'd rather stay with dictionaries ):

```
NODES:
  - node1:
    server: host1
    script: manage1
  - node2:
    server: host2
    script: manage2
```

for above list simple file creation works correctly:

```
- name: Create files
  file:
    path: "/etc/init.d/{{item.script}}"
    state: touch
  with_items: "{{ NODES }}"
```

but analogical file creation from template does not:

```
- name: Create files template
  file:
    dest: "/etc/init.d/{{item.script}}"
    src: templ.j2
  with_items: "{{ NODES }}"
```

I'm starting with Ansible, and is not easy to understand especially second case.

Comment: Update the question with the template `templ.j2`.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: *"I can't find a way to get"*

```
/etc/init.d/manage1
/etc/init.d/manage2
```

A:

Use `item.value.script`

```
- name: Create files from templates
  template:
    src: "templ.j2"
    dest: "/etc/init.d/{{ item.value.script }}"
  loop: "{{ NODES|dict2items }}"
  when: "{{ 'script' in item.value }}"
```

Comment: Indeed, it works, seems I tried 20 others options but not suggested by you. Thanks